# SharePoint 2010 Content DB rapidly increasing in Size

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-database, database-server

**SharePoint Health Analyzer** rule detected the unused free space in `WSS_Content Database`, so to free up the space I had to shrink the Database.
**Before shrinking**, the size of content DB was **259 GB**. **After Shrinking** its reduce to **199 GB**.
It was stable for 2 days but after that Content DB suddenly started to increase in size and ended up on **272 GB**.

According to **SQL Report** of Disk space used by Table it showing near about **200 GB** data. So what causes allocation of extra space and is there any way to regain the space?

Should I shrink it again (I know shrinking is not recommended by Microsoft) because SharePoint Health Analyzer again shows that the Content DB having unused space?

Please suggest useful solution for the problem above.

Comment: Is any one handle similar kind of situation or is there any resolution...?
Please Suggest..

Comment: `1.` What's the name of the table in your Content DB with the large growth per your SQL Report? When you shrink the data file, you cause database level fragmentation so you should also reindex when you do this. It's not going to help much if the transactions cause it to grow again so you'll need to capture what's causing it to grow transaction wise at the SQL Server level to see what's causing this. `2.` What version of SQL Server are you running? Are you a sysadmin on the SQL Server instance with the Content DB or do you have a DBA that needs to assist with this level of troubleshooting?

Comment: AuditData & AllDocsstreams are the two tables, which taking near about 205 GB & remaining all others are of maximum 2 GB collectively. So for what the extra 60 GB space is allocated for..?
I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Is there any solution to Deal with the growth of Content Database..??

Answer (score 0):

have your DBA look at the file growth increment on the SQL Server.  Some DBAs leave this at the default, and that means the log file can grow at 10% increments which can cause the db to blow up.  Sometimes the database file growth can also be incorrectly set.
Here's a KB article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315512